# Do I need Exchange Server for SMTP only

Tags: smtp

I have a Web based application, through which i intend to send an email notifications to the users who singns in.
I have put a SMTP server on Windows 2008 R2 Standard edition for the same.
Do i need anything else apart from the SMTP server, like Lotus or Exchange server.
Again for clarification I only need to send Emails to the users and I am not suppose to recieve emails through it.

Looking for help soon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, so long as you have an SMTP injection point, you're good to go.

There are a few things you should take into account when setting something like that up to reduce the chances of your outgoing mail getting flagged as spam (SPF, etc...). Consider SPF records and ensuring your DNS is properly configured and all that.

Comment: Hi McJeff, 
Many thanks for ur reply.
Thanks for the info, this is really usefull.
A Little explanation: If I have a website and user creates an account on it, after this process, an email wud b sent to the user.The srvrs invloved in this scneraio r (web,App,DB,AD & SMTP) all r on seperate physical machines.Now, the user creates an account,this would b done with the help of WebMethods srvr which is seperate frm above mentioned srvrs n is integrated. the webmethods hav to invoke the mail request to send email via SMTP srvr. 
Now,how this wud b achieved n what do i need to do on SMTP srvr.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking? How do you get the message from code to the SMTP system?

Comment: you got it now McJeff, This is my real question, what do i need to do to enable sending emails from my SMTP server. do i need to write some commands in the code or some forwarding mechanism?

Comment: The short answer is "yes, you need to handle it in code."  Your specific framework will have a mechanism for configuring an outbound SMTP connection. That's framework dependent. Perhaps XML, perhaps YAML, perhaps in the actual method that sends the mail. You'll need to set that up so that it uses your SMTP machine as a relay point. 

How? That I really don't know. Depends on your framework, version, code, and so on. If you're wondering how to do it programmatically, might be more of a stackoverflow.com question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need anything else. The SMTP server built into IIS can send email to the internet successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Windows SMTP is perfectly fine for this.  You should look at locking it down so that only the web app can use it to send, and so that it doesn't accept incoming email.  I'm not certain how much of that is possible with Windows SMTP, but as much of it as you can do is advisable.